# Code is adding items to list but unable to get any data from db

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I am using AngularFire2 in Ionic2 in which i'm trying to fetch a list and display it on view using ngFor and also pushing new item to firebase, my code is adding items to list porperly but unable to get any data from db.
following is by service

```
constructor(public afd:AngularFireDatabase) {}

getShoppingItems(){

 return this.afd.list('/shoppingItems');

}
```

after console.log(Array.from(this.getShoppingItems())) i get the following result.

and following is data in db which m expecting to get in response

```
{"shoppingItems":{"-KwW3BgGsBfd0MeMqeTL":"Rohan","-KwWAK5zrEfwCYM-KdlT":"Vikas"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This should be in Provider.ts

getShoppingItems(){

 return this.afd.list('/shoppingItems');

}

//In Page.ts, declear shoppingitems as an observable list
shoppingItems: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;


//Still in Page.ts, inside its constuctor, call the method in provider service
this.shoppingItems = this.provider_service.getShoppingItems();

//In Page.html, do this

<ion-list *ngFor=let item of shoppingItems | async ></ion-list>
```

Comment: @rohanpadwalkar whats in your page.html?

Comment: my page.html <ion-list *ngFor=let item of shoppingItems | async ></ion-list>